# Proper way to register an EF4 ObjectContext using Unity?

Tags: entity-framework, unity-container

I'm having problems with my EF4 ObjectContext in Unity.  Specifically, when Unity tries to resolve my ObjectContext with the following code:

```
container.RegisterType<ObjectContext, MyObjectContext>(
    new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
```

It gives me:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

I assumed it would be able to use the hard-wired connection that was set up when creating the EF4 data model (used with the parameterless constructor), but it seems that I have to explicitly pass this in:

```
container.RegisterType<ObjectContext, MyObjectContext>(
    new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(connectionString));
```

Also, since this method seems to create an instance of my (disposable) ObjectContext, when is the proper place to destroy it?

Or, should I be doing this differently altogether?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid." is obviously not a result of failed resolving of the registered type but it's an EF exception.

The EF designer should have created a context with a constructor like this:

```
public MyObjectContext() : base("name=MyObjectContext", "MyObjectContext")
{
    ...
}
```

and added a connection string to app.config/web.config. Assuming that the designer didn't do this wrong I would exclude that this "named connection" is "not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid". It remains that the "named connection" is "not found in the configuration".

Did you check if the connection string is in the app.config/web.config **of the project where you resolve the ObjectContext**? For instance, if you have your EF model in a separate class library then EF creates an app.config with the proper connection string in that project. If you are consuming this model from another project which references your EF class library you need to copy the connection string manually to the app.config/web.config of this project. EF won't look into the configuration of your class library.

Regarding your question what's the proper place to destroy the ObjectContext the most general answer would be: "When you don't need it anymore". It's difficult to give an advice without knowing your project context. If the data access you need is in one method, I think you could write:

```
using (var context = container.Resolve<ObjectContext>())
{
    // your EF operations
}
```

Comment: Thanks Slauma, I had not thought to check for an app.config in my EF project.  You're right it's there.  Copying that connection string to my web.config file allowed me to get it back to a parameterless constructor.  Regarding the disposing of ObjectContext, I need to dig into this more, and may open this up on another question.  I'm using some sample implementation I found, and need to understand it better before I can determine where best to dispose of ObjectContext.